# Marked as private warning after changing colour of up arrow

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-support-library

After defining a custom colour for the back arrow in the action bar, a warning is then returned. What can be done to get rid of this warning?

```
        final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

> The resource @drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha is marked as private in com.android.support:appcompat-v7

Comment: I've seen a few posts regarding issues accessing system drawables after the latest Android Studio update. This doesn't answer your question directly, but I'd recommend [this](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin "Material Icons Generator") plugin as a means of easily importing Material Design icons to your project.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See [Choose resources to make public](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#PrivateResources) for the reason.

In short, drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha is a private resource of  appcompat-v7 and is intended to be used **only** by that library. You should not use it.

If you really want to use it, copy it to your project

Comment: I need to override it, why should I copy the resources?

Comment: this is better way

Answer (score 14):

Instead of doing Mohammad's

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'PrivateResource'
    } 
}
```

I'd recommend to do the following, which is a local fix for a statement. The advantage is not having to deactivate the lint-checks globally (which can easily be forgotten to activate again later on).

For XML:

```
tools:ignore="PrivateResource"
```

For Code:

```
@SuppressLint("PrivateResource")
```

Effectively, your code then should look something like this:

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    tools:ignore="PrivateResource" />
```

Code:

```
@SuppressLint("PrivateResource")
final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's a bug in android 
this post form a project member in Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker

Replying to a similar [Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183120)

> The root cause here is that when a library depends on another library,
>   it imports all the resources from any libraries it depends on into its
>   own declared R.txt (in the AAR file).
>
> However, it doesn't include the public.txt declaration from those
>   dependencies, so now it ends up exposing these symbols as declared but
>   not public -- e.g. private.
>
> I'm considering two fix alternatives:
>
> (1) in the resource visibility lookup for a library, remove any
>   symbols imported from a dependency (whether or not that dependency
>   provides visibility information), or
>
> (2) reverse the visibility lookup logic: if we find a symbol as public
>   in any library, consider it public rather than the current logic which
>   says that if a symbol is declared as private anywhere, it is.
>
> I think I'm going with 2; the current logic doesn't make sense when
>   considering the scenario that symbols end up inlined in downstream
>   libraries.

as they said :

> The only workaround for now is to turn off the private resource lint
>   check:
>
> ```
>     android {
>         lintOptions {
>             disable 'PrivateResource'
>         } 
>     }
> ```

they are saying it was fixed but I had run through this issue today and I'm using android studio 1.5.1 and gradle 1.5

Answer (score 0):

While I prefer to keep the Lint suppressions as close to the source as possible, as it's done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34152740/383676), if that doesn't work it's also possible to list the suppressions in a `lint.xml` file located in your `app` folder. It would look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
<issue id="<issue-id>">
    <ignore path="<path-to-source>.<file-extension>"/>
</issue>
```

Where issue-id is the type you want to suppress, for example UseSparseArrays. Android Studio will also autocomplete this field for you.