# How to fix "The resource @style/Theme_AppCompat is marked as private in com.android.support:appcompat-v7"

Tags: android, lint

How to fix lint-warning: The resource `@style/Theme_AppCompat` is marked as **private** in `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` ?

Comment: Are you sure there is an underscore? I thought the theme was `Theme.AppCompat`.  If you'd like to ignore the warning. Answers are here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927273/marked-as-private-warning-after-changing-colour-of-up-arrow

Answer (score 0):

Its a warning. To ignore it just add tools:ignore="PrivateResource" to your xml code. I would recommend copying Theme_AppCompat and making a Theme_AppCompat_New and using that.

Comment: I do not like to disable warning. I'd like to fix source of warning.

Comment: Okay .. Just copy the Theme_AppCompat theme and make a Theme_AppCompat_New and use that instead