# Android Studio Error - Using Private Resources

Tags: java, android

Please someone could help me, when i installed de Android Studio the following error appeared. The error:

1. Using Private Resources Text:

[image]

2. Using Private Resources Design:

[image]

In the message it says copy the resources into own project instead but I do not know how I do it.

> The resource @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is marked as
>   private in com.android.support:design  Private resources should not be
>   referenced; the may not be present everywhere, and even where they are
>   they may disappear without notice.  To fix this, copy the resource
>   into your own project instead.

Comment: Can you add error message as text rather than image?

Comment: This is the error message

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927273/marked-as-private-warning-after-changing-colour-of-up-arrow

Comment: @GabrielMelo how you solved ?

Comment: I copy and past this line: tools:ignore="PrivateResource" below the line that the error was occurring.  
                            
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="PrivateResource"