# Colour is private in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I keep getting this error message when compiling:

error: resource android:color/foreground_material_dark is private.

I used this material in this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/newbackground">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rollButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/button_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/foreground_material_dark"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34152740/5110595)

Comment: In short, **"@android:color/foreground_material_dark"** comes from appcompat-v7 and is intended to be used only by that library. You should not use it.

Answer (score 1):

That case you should make Make custom color like this color.xml

```
<color name="mycolor">#0288D1</color>
```

then use it

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/rollButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:textColor="@color/mycolor"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **tools:ignore="PrivateResource"** on the widget where you are using the color